# Unexpected Run Configuration

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm

While using PyCharm for a while now I encountered a problem executing a certain scripts.

Usually, I right-click the script-tab and choose "Run <script_name>..."

At some point the context menu changed and reads: "Run Python tests in <script_name>..."
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnpvX.png)

What have I done and how can I revert this?

Thanks in advance.

After, I tried to tinker in the Run Configs of that specific script but was not able to find anything which makes sense to me.

Other scripts are not affected.

Comment: What does the file look like and what is the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your default settings by doing this :
[restore default settings of pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN25V.jpg)

More information on : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults

Or another solution is to uninstall your pycharm and then reinstall it again.